# How a then() method returns a value

Tags: javascript

```
transform(profilePictureUrl: string): any {
    return this.methodA(profilePictureUrl).then((res)=>{
        return res;
    })
}

private async methodA(pPUrl: string) {
    var accessCredentials = await SDKInitializer.GetInstance().GetSessionCredentials();
    return accessCredentials.AccessToken
}
```

In the above method GetSessionCredentials() returns a promise which i want to resolve by using then() and return its value.

It returns me this
ZoneAwarePromise {**zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: "braj ankit"
__proto**: Object

Comment: Yes, `transform` will return a promise. You need to handle it the same way you're already handling promises: either with `transform(...).then(...)`, or with `await transform(...)`.

Comment: is there any another way ?

Comment: No, there is not.